# AGPS settings loading instead of location & security

Tags: java, android, gps

I have a simple if statement check to determine if the GPS is turned on on my app.

This works perfectly on the emulator, but when installed on an actual device instead of the 'Location & security' menu being loaded as called from the intent, it is loading the AGPS option. This menu does not allow me to turn the GPS on and I have to manually naviagte to the 'Location & security' menu.

This is my alertDialog builder code. As shown using an intent to call 'ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS'.

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

To highlight the issue further ill use the following screenshots:

This is the screen I want to load through my intent:

[image]

The menu that is currently being loaded:

[image]

How do I enable my intent to load the first menu instead of the second?

Comment: Which device is this? It shouldn't even have an AGPS screen, let alone open one on a documented intent.

Comment: @RaghavSood It is strange. The device is an ACER E320 Liquid Express. As stated, on the emulator this loads the location & security menu perfectly.

Comment: I've never heard of this device in particular. If it works on the emulator, it should work on the majority of Android devices. FWIW, it opens up the correct screen on my LG optimus one and 3 nexus devices.